# Given a custom Shape, how do you increase the size to fit a frame in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a series of custom defined `Shape` and a `ZStack` that has a set frame, is there a way to increase the size of each custom `Shape` that can be of various sizes to fit the `Zstack` frame?

[image]

Code that will draw various `Shape` given points.

```swift
struct DrawShape: Shape {

    var points: [CGPoint]
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path: Path = Path()

        guard let startingPoint = points.first else {
            return path
        }

        path.move(to: startingPoint)

        for pointLocation in points {
            
            path.addLine(to: pointLocation)
            
        }

        return path
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for your shapes?

Comment: @aheze added! It's actually a series of points that I pass in, not sure if that changes the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

1. Draw the path, as usual
2. Get the [`boundingRect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/boundingrect) of the path
3. Determine the scale factor needed for the path

   - **`rect` is the available area of the shape**
   - if `boundingRect` is fatter than `rect`, use their widths
   - if `boundingRect` is skinnier than `rect`, use their heights
4. Draw a new path, this time with the scaled points and offset (if needed)

   - if the origin of the path isn't `(0, 0)`, each new point needs to have the origin subtracted
5. Return the new path

```
struct DrawShape: Shape {
    var points: [CGPoint]
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        
        /// draw the path
        var path = Path()
        guard let startingPoint = points.first else { return path }
        path.move(to: startingPoint)
        for pointLocation in points {
            path.addLine(to: pointLocation)
        }
        
        /// aspect fit scale
        let scale: CGFloat
        if path.boundingRect.height / path.boundingRect.width < rect.height / rect.width {
            scale = rect.width / path.boundingRect.width /// boundingRect is fatter
        } else {
            scale = rect.height / path.boundingRect.height /// boundingRect is skinnier
        }

        /// draw the scaled path
        var scaledPath = Path()
        scaledPath.move(to: convertPoint(startingPoint, offset: path.boundingRect.origin, scale: scale))
        for pointLocation in points {
            scaledPath.addLine(to: convertPoint(pointLocation, offset: path.boundingRect.origin, scale: scale))
        }
        
        /// return the scaled path
        return scaledPath
    }
    
    /// point = original point
    /// offset = in case the origin of `boundingRect` isn't (0,0), make sure to offset each point
    /// scale = how much to scale the point by
    func convertPoint(_ point: CGPoint, offset: CGPoint, scale: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: (point.x - offset.x) * scale, y: (point.y - offset.y) * scale)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
            
            DrawShape(points: [
                CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
                CGPoint(x: 200, y: 0),
                CGPoint(x: 100, y: 250),
                CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            ])
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 500)
    }
}
```

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Small triangle at top-left of blue background] | [image: Triangle scaled to fit width of background] |

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much. This worked like a charm for all the straight line Shape that I have, I'm curious if it'll be any different for Arc/Curved shapes? I have yet to try it but curious on your thoughts @aheze

Comment: @elyakshaver it should work... just make sure to call `convertPoint` on both `center` and `radius`.

Comment: got it! I'll try it out. Thanks @aheze!!

Comment: @aheze Is there any way to modify it to fit X number of shapes without touching each other (given their proportion to each other) in a rect?
eg - 3 circles, 2nd circle is 50% of the 1st, 3rd is 25% of first. (Like a packed bubble chart)

Comment: @KunalVerma yes that would be possible, you’ll just need to do some math

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to fit any path inside the proposed rectangle keeping aspect ratio. And it's rather short way.

```
struct FittingShape: Shape {
    var absolutePath: Path
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let boundingRect = absolutePath.boundingRect
        let scale = min(rect.width/boundingRect.width, rect.height/boundingRect.height)
        let scaled = absolutePath.applying(.init(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
        let scaledBoundingRect = scaled.boundingRect
        let offsetX = scaledBoundingRect.midX - rect.midX
        let offsetY = scaledBoundingRect.midY - rect.midY
        return scaled.offsetBy(dx: -offsetX, dy: -offsetY)
    }
}
```

Test it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var path = Path {
        $0.addLines([
            CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
            CGPoint(x: 200, y: 0),
            CGPoint(x: 100, y: 250),
            CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        ])
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
            FittingShape(absolutePath: path) // The shape is centered
            //DrawShape(points: points) // This gives sligtly different result: the shape is sticked to the top
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 500)
    }
}
```